# RISCV VERILOG HDL code

Tags: verilog, hdl, riscv

I get the following error when compiling RISCV VERILOG HDL on Xilinx ISE:

It says
"Unsupported System Function Call" in the following code at line 296 in module vscale_pipeline

```
295: ifndef SYNTHESIS
296: PC_WB <= $random;
```

Comment: Please show some code, then people could help you to improve/fix your script. Add more detail on your problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This sounds like the verilog you have isn't supported by Xilinx ISE. I would contact the providers of that code.

Comment: Is `SYNTHESIS` defined and defined before this line of code? Compiling order matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot Morgan for your reply: I downloaded the code from the website: https://github.com/ucb-bar/vscale

Comment: I got the information from: http://riscv.org/2015/09/risc-v-in-verilog/ .. Cannot contact their help service though.. I might be missing something..

Comment: And dont know where SYNTHESIS variable is defined.. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Some synthesis tools define the `SYNTHESIS` macro so that it is easier to skip non-synthesizable code in synthesis using

```
`ifdef SYNTHESIS
...
`endif
```

blocks, as is done in this code.

Xilinx XST does not define this macro by default, so you have to configure XST manually to define the macro during synthesis. See [this Xilinx AR](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/37747.html) for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

$random isn't synthesizable, so take it out