# What is the significance and how to use `define SYNTHESIS in rocket-chip/vsim?

Tags: riscv

I see a bunch of

`ifndef SYNTHESIS

some_variable={1{$random}};

statements in my generated RTL verilog. These statements don't get synthesized during gate level synthesis. When I do:

make output/rv64ui-p-auipc.vpd (in /rocket-chip/vsim, as an example)

I want to generate the waveforms based on the RTL that the synthesis tool will see. I tried accomplishing this by setting '+define+SYNTHESIS=1' as a VCS option, but doing so will create some sort of infinite loop when running the test.

What are those `ifndef statements actually doing? And what is the signifiance of them (i.e. why does defining the SYNTHESIS variable here create an infinite loop?)

Thanks!

Comment: See this answer I wrote to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37269827/2213720

Comment: @CliffordVienna Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The Rocket Chip simulation infrastructure depends on all state being initialized to 0 or 1.  Some simulators (such as Synopsys VCS) may initialize registers to Xs if they are not initialized at the start of simulation, which can cause the simulation to fail (this is the behavior you observed when you defined `SYNTHESIS`).  Because the tests ought to be robust to random initialization, pre-synthesis RTL is annotated to randomly initialize register state.

Synthesis tools (such as Synopsys Design Compiler) will ignore RTL wrapped in these `ifndef` blocks.  Note that simulations of post-synthesis RTL must also initialize all registers to 0 or 1 for the simulation to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want post synthesis gate level simulation results to match pre-synthesis RTL. So, instead of initializing to random, think I'll initialize everything to 0. Seems this works. Thanks again!